# What's the cost effective way to simulate data streaming for demo

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataset, google-cloud-dataflow

My current pipeline is `Google Cloud Storage > Dataflow > BigQuery`. I'm planning to simulate data streaming for pre-launched demo. My datasets are pretty large.

I'm relatively new to Google Cloud Platform, are there any products that can help with data simulation more cost effectively? I'm open to other Google compatible products too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most cost effective solution should be simulating the streaming data in memory on Dataflow directly using [TestStream](https://beam.apache.org/blog/test-stream/). Then you don't need to use products other than Dataflow for your demo.